# Program to get input string, replace blanks in string with TAB space in C

Tags: c

Program to get an input string, convert blanks in it to TAB spaces and print the final string.

Eg: 'This is a book' string input should be converted to 'This    is    a    book' output with tab spaces in between the 4 words

My code-

```
int main()
{
    int i=0;
   char text[20];
   fputs("enter some text: ", stdout);
   fflush(stdout);
   if ( fgets(text, sizeof text, stdin) != NULL )
   {
    for(i=0;text[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(text[i]=='\0')
        printf("blank");
    }
      printf("text = \"%s\"\n", text);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question? It sounds like you are asking us to do your assignment for you. Have you tried to do anything yourself?

Comment: nt main()
{
 int i=0;
   char text[20];
   fputs("enter some text: ", stdout);
   fflush(stdout);
   if ( fgets(text, sizeof text, stdin) != NULL )
   {
    for(i=0;text[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
     if(text[i]=='\0')
     printf("blank");
    }
      printf("text = \"%s\"\n", text);
   }
   return 0;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This replaces every `' '` with `'\t'`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char text[1000];

    fputs("enter some text: ", stdout);
    fflush(stdout);

    if (fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (text[i])
        {
            if (text[i] == ' ')
                text[i] = '\t';
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", text);

    return 0;
}
```